# Pandas datareader limit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

i use pandas datareader to obtain quotes for a large number of stocks (via stooq). It works fine for the first 100 or so stocks. Then i run the same program again (with the same list of stock codes), it starts returning empty dataframe. Used a different machine, had the same issue. (Ie first attempt works fine, then second attempt returns empty dataframe).In fact, i also tried calling single stock via iex as a source after such issue appears, still returns an empty dataframe. lookIn the documentation, it didnt specify any download limit though. Is there any recommendation? Many thanks